# Inherit from collections.Counter: 'fromkeys' is abstract

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract, python-collections

I have a python class that inherit from `collections.Counter`:

```
class Analyzer(collections.Counter):
   pass
```

When I use pylint on this code, its answer is:

> W: Method 'fromkeys' is abstract in class 'Counter' but is not overridden (abstract-method)

I checked the implementation of `collections.Counter` on my machine, and effectively, this method is not implemented (and a comment helps to understand why):

```
class Counter(dict):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, iterable, v=None):
        # There is no equivalent method for counters because setting v=1
        # means that no element can have a count greater than one.
        raise NotImplementedError(
            'Counter.fromkeys() is undefined.  Use Counter(iterable) instead.')
```

However, I don't really know how to implement this method, if `Counter` itself does not…

What is the way to solve this warning in this situation?

Comment: Just ignore the warning? Pylint is being wrong, and misinterpreting things.

Comment: I mean, a naive solution might be to implement it in the say way as in `collections.Counter`. But this shouldn't even be necessary...

Comment: It's a warning not an error

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is the way I handled it until now…

Comment: @JaredGoguen Or, instead of re-implement it, just reuse the leaking implementation: `fromkeys = collections.Counter.fromkeys`. But as you said, this shouldn't even be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two separate way of thinking.

- Consider `Counter` as abstract (as pylint does, as [Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547844/4636017) explained). Then, the class `Analyzer`  must implement `fromkeys` or also be abstract. But then, one should not be able to instanciate `Counter`.
- Consider `Counter` as concrete, even if you cannot use its `fromkeys` method. Then, pylint's warning must be disabled (as it is wrong in this case, see [Jared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547844/4636017) to kown how), and the class `Analyzer` is also concrete and does not need to implement this method.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186843/pylint-w0223-method-is-abstract-in-class-but-is-not-overridden) should answer some of the questions here. Basically, pylint checks for `NotImplementedError` exceptions being raised to determine whether a method is abstract (a false positive in this case). Adding the comment `#pylint: disable=W0223` will disable this check.

A similar issue is also raised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981978/what-makes-pylint-think-my-class-is-abstract).

Comment: However, if pylint consider `Counter` as an abstract class because `fromkeys` raises `NotImplementedError`, it must consider incorrect to instanciate it. Isn't it?